# How to change IP address using network-shell with argument as IP

Tags: php, batch-file, networking, cmd, netsh

I am trying to run the below batch script using PHP (it runs fine from command prompt) to change the IP using the argument passed

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
netsh int ip set address "EDU_LAN_Connection" static 172.31.%1.110 255.255.255.0 172.31.%1.1 1
```

In PHP:

```
 system("cmd /c C:\EDU_Project\change_ip.bat 6");
```

I get the following error when running the PHP script:

```
Invalid address parameter (172.31.61.1 1). It should be a valid IPv4 address.
```

I am not sure how to use delayedexpansion with argument. Please help !

Comment: I think you should look into how IPV4 addresses are formatted

Comment: you're trying to assign a class B address, which is all fine. A standard class B address would be (172.x.y.z), You're currently doing 172.x.y.z A, where A is. Is invalid for an IP construct, hence my original comment

Comment: This error is same as discussed in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21824179/ip-configuration-from-batch-file but I am not sure how to use arguments with delayedexpansion

Answer (score 1):

Batch parameters are addressed with `%1` only. Not `%1%`

Change your batchfile accordingly:

```
 netsh int ip set address "EDU_LAN_Connection" static 172.31.%1.110 255.255.255.0 172.31.%1.1 1
```

Comment: Thanks I made that change, script runs fine on command prompt but I still get this error when ran from PHP:

    Invalid address parameter (172.31.6.110 255.255.255.0 172.31.6.1). It should be a valid IPv4 address. Ping request could not find host 172.31.6.1 -n 2. Please check the name and try again.

Comment: I have edited a typo in my answer. Try again please.

Comment: Thanks for the help Stephan, yeah I already saw that typo it still does not work. Works fine on command prompt though.

Comment: The error though has changed to this:

Invalid address parameter (172.31.6.110 255.255.255.0 172.31.6.1). It should be a valid IPv4 address

Comment: I can see no reason for this. But I notice, that the last "1" (for "metric") is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for system function and passing an argument to the batch file. I ran the netsh command directly from PHP using shell_exec:

```
$var= 18;
shell_exec('netsh int ip set address name=\"EDU_LAN_Connection\" static 172.31.'.$var.'.110 255.255.255.0 172.31.'.$var.'.1 1');
```